# Swift: Making dictionary array values mutable

Tags: swift, performance, dictionary

This is a coding pattern I use frequently in other languages, e.g. Obj-C:

I have a dictionary whose values are arrays, to which I may add zero or more items.

I wrote this code in Swift 5:

```
var intsForString = [String:[Int]]()

func add(value: Int, forKey: String) {
    var ints = intsForString[forKey]
    if ints == nil {
        ints = [Int]()
        intsForString[forKey] = ints
    }
    ints!.append(value)
}

add(value: 1, forKey: "a")
add(value: 2, forKey: "a")

print("\(intsForString["a"]!)") // prints an empty array instead of `[1,2]`
```

I had expected that I could get a reference to the `ints` value in the dictionary and then modify it. However, it appears I get a copy of the array in the dict, and when I modify the `ints` array, it will not update the array stored in the dict.

**Is there a way to get a mutable reference to the array in the dictionary, without resorting to `NSDictionary` and `NSArray`?**

### Work-around

I can, as a work-around, update the array inside the dictionary by moving the line

```
intsForString[forKey] = ints
```

past the `ints!.append(value)` line.

However, I find that inefficient, because that requires another key lookup, and it also leads to the array being needlessly copied and re-created, then disposed again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of that function you can do

```
intsForString["a",default: []].append(1)
```

Comment: Oddly, that is not only more elegant but also solves my issue. But why? What makes this one mutable while my solution won't?

Comment: Similarly, `var ints = intsForString["a",default:[]]; ints.append(1)` won't work, either. That is so weird.

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann It works because [`Dictionary.subscript(_:default:)` uses a `_modify` accessor](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/520e12430e4766e9f186750116198bb5ed9ca0c9/stdlib/public/core/Dictionary.swift#L895-L906), a not-yet-released feature which is able to give your code a temporary reference to the location to write a new value (or the default) into. This feature hasn't been stabilized/publicized yet, but technically, you could write your own `_modify` accessors (just expect the feature to change as it goes through a Swift Evolution proposal)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you found one solution and got another one in an answer, but you may be interested to know why you had this problem in the first place. In Swift, arrays and dictionaries are *value types*, while `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` are *reference types*. That means that in Swift, when your code executes this line:

```
var ints = intsForString[forKey]
```

You have already created a copy of the array by assigning it to a new variable. Any changes you make to `ints` affect that copy, not the one in the dictionary. *Value type* here means that when you make this assignment, you're assigning the value of the array. It's the same as if you were using something like an integer variable, and you assigned the value to a new variable.

If you did the equivalent thing with `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`, you'd be assigning a pointer-- a *reference*-- to the original array. If you changed the array, you'd be changing the original array. *Reference types* here means that when you make the (equivalent) assignment, you're assigning a reference to the original array.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I'm still getting used to the idea that arrays are value types. It makes me a bit worried about runtime performance when I assign arrays to new variables, though. I guess that's why I should be using "let", though what happens when I have a "var a1:[...]" and assign that to "let a2 = a1", and then modify a1? That would require that a copy of a1 has to be made on the let statement, making this quite slow if the array is large, right? And isn't there a way to get references to data of value types so that I can solve my conumdrum with a tmp variable?

Comment: Swift uses copy-on-write for arrays and dictionaries, so there's no immediate performance effect from an assignment-- only later, and only if needed. In your example, since `a1` and `a2` are value types, it doesn't matter that one uses `let`. As soon as you assign `a2 = a1`, you have a new copy.